# Confusion rendering unescaped HTML and newlines

Tags: angularjs

I have a forum like site, where people should be able to add strings like:

```
<<<<<
>.<
```

etc.

Also I want to preserve the new lines. Besides I replace many newlines in the server with 1.

For first feature I found the solution is to use ng-bind-html="myText"

that works.

But I have a problem with the newlines, not matter what I do, they are not displayed.

If I don't do anything (also no replacements in the server), they are rendered as newlines in the source and not displayed.

If I replace them with `<br>` or `<br/>` before rendering, they show as source -> `<br>` or `<br/>`.

If I don't use ng-bind-html anymore, and render the text as normal expression, I get escaped html: `&lt;br&gt;` (besides, in this case, the strings mentioned first also don't work).

What do I have to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle? it doesn't look like you have to use "ng-bind-html". you don't want to render that, you want to encode and decode the string properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more of a CSS issue. Use: `white-space: pre;`.

Comment: Ah! I didn't think that this was a CSS issue... but this fixes everything, thanks!

Comment: Accepted but it needs an improvement - with this the lines are cut horizontally when space is small or text to large. I needed is `white-space: pre-wrap`